# passing a string into a method, converting to json and then deserialising in .net

Tags: .net, json

There are plenty of posts on this topic but I still don't quite get the underlying theory.

In my .net controller i've got a method:

```
public void createModel(string jsonString)
{

}
```

The jsonString is this:

```
[{"Player":{"weight":220,"height":190,"distance":20},"Results":{"game1":60,"game2":90,"game3":40....
```

So I understand this is an array. But in the first instance it's passed into the function as a string. I know there are a whole of deserialisers, newtonsoft etc. but i just don't quite get the process:

eg. 
1. take string and turn it into json eg. var json = Json.Parse(jsonString)
2. somehow get array out of json
3. If I want "Results" how do I just access that?

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: It's *already* JSON. JSON is the text representation. You want to call `var players = JsonConverter.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(jsonString);` or similar

Comment: Thx! So if everything that is a string and is structured as json is actually json when is JSON.parse(str) necessary?

Comment: Well I don't know which library you're using to call `Json.Parse` or what the result is, which makes it hard to say...

Comment: Ok. Thanks. And the fact it's in an array. Does that change how it needs to be deserialised?

Comment: Yes, you need to serialize it to a collection like a list or an array, as per my first comment...

Comment: Ok. But what doesn't make sense to me is that in line one you suggested var players= Json.......<List<Player>>(jsonString). But in the json I provided there is two objects one is Player the other is Results. Does JsonConverter know which object it is getting out of the json string? Because I have done what you suggested but if I Debug.WriteLine(players[0].weight) I keep getting the result 0. Cheers.

Comment: Ok. But what doesn't make sense to me is that in line one you suggested var players= Json.......<List<Player>>(jsonString).

Comment: Well whatever you want to call it - your array contains an object with two properties: Player and Results. So deserialize it to a list of objects with those properties.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json string is not in correct format. An array means collection of same types. If you want player array then it should contain only player details. Create another array in Json string for results.